# Data segregation for high confidentiality

Tags: security, help, administrator

I work at a bank and we currently use one single org to simplify our processes, but we have a department with highly confidential info.
I’m trying to find a way to “separate” the data from this department, since not even system administrators (which are it personnel) should see the prod data !
Is there a way to do this in salesforce ?

Comment: I've changed the title of this question to avoid idioms that might be offensive to some folks. I don't think that was your intent, but wanted to avoid that outcome.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way you can hide data from System Administrators. If that's your use case, you need a second org.

System Administrators (and users with [View All Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm) generally) ignore Sharing Rules, and System Administrators always have the ability to elevate their own privileges in the org by altering Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think on doing this is marking fields on the object as encrypted using classic encryption. This does have some limitations as to what fields this can be applied to (no standard fields) but it brings into play a new permission "View Encrypted Permission". If the user doesn't have this permission (system admin for example) they will not see the field values. This is trivial for a system admin to override though although at least you will have it logged in your audit trail. Shield use to have this functionality but was removed a while ago all shield could do is leave a better log as to who accessed the records and when.

[See encryption here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_platform_encryption_implementation_guide.pdf)